# Best method to deploy ExtJs Grid in large scale project

Tags: deployment, extjs, grid

Its been quite sometime, I've been evaluating ExtJs Grid. So far so good and I love the control and API. I have some genuine doubts regarding deploying ExtJs Grid in production environment. Here they goes:

How can I deploy ExtJs Grid into a large-scale project? Suppose I have a huge project, which contains more than 100 Grids. In that case, how can I handle those Grids?

1. Do I have to maintain seperate JavaScript file for each grid? That means, If I have 100 grids, do I need to maintain 100 JS files?
2. Do I have to maintain a wrapper JS file, which can create all those my 100 Grids, as per ther arguments that I pass to a method?

Which one is better? Or is there any better methods available? Can someone please shed some info on deploying ExtJs Grid in a large-scale project?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain your project? 100 grids or 100 models/datastores?

I would create a database with model/source/grid column definitions, and build the ext grids dynamically by mapping the data with json. This is pretty trivial once you make a beforeRender listener that has a ajax request within it, then in the success routine of the ajax you create or populate the model/source/grid definitions and ... done.

You can see this technique (non grid) for example ...

```
var areaEast = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    region: 'east',
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    width: 200,
    title: 'east',
    items: [ ],
    layout:'accordion',
    autoScroll: true,
    listeners : {
        beforeRender : function() {

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: './js/tabs.pl',
                disableCaching: false,
                success: function(response){
                    var text = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                    Ext.each( text.rows, function(row, index) {
                        areaEast.add( row );
                    });
                },
            });

        },
    },
});
```

... and some json like what follows will produce a couple of ext items[] on the fly ...

```
Content-Type: application/json

{"rows":[{"html":"str_0.720264353647025","iconCls":"ico_home","title":"tab_1","xtype":"panel"},
 {"html":"str_0.967244391419577","iconCls":"ico_gear","title":"tab_2","xtype":"panel"},
 {"html":"str_0.713014552355148","iconCls":"ico_home","title":"tab_3","xtype":"panel"},
 {"html":"str_0.0254531761575763","iconCls":"ico_gear","title":"tab_4","xtype":"panel"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  What I have in mind is to keep a template for each Grid, in XML format in server; which will be pulled to client-side via Ajax in Grid's PreRender event. This xml file will have the details of Column structures and additional detals if any. Like you said, on the success event of Ajax in PreRender, I'll parse those XML to create the structure/model of my grid; which later on sends an Ajax call to the database, for loading data in XML/JSON format. Hows that?Sounds cool? Or is there any better method? Thanks!

Comment: Well,json/xml really a pick your poison situation. I have an cgi that shows a tree of 'reports'. Each report is a definition in a database table like you describe grid if any, columns, datasource, headers, chart type if any, axis setup, etc. This is all used to form the page like you describe using the technique above.

Comment: Well. Then let me try with JSON/XML and the PreRender event. Thanks for the suggestions :) Cheers!